# ¿Como manipular eventos que están dentro de un JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Tengo esto en `html`:

```
<ul class="simplefilter">
  Simple filter controls:   
</ul>
```

y en un archivo `JS` dinamicamente le estoy cargando una data en `<li>`

```
$(".simplefilter").append('<li data-filter="' + data[i].id_categoria + '">' + data[i].desc_categoria +'</li>');
```

aparte de eso tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
//Simple filter controls
    $('.simplefilter li').click(function() {
        $('.simplefilter li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

la idea es que cuando yo de `click` en alguno de los `<li>` que se están generando dinamicamente dentro de la etiqueta `<ul class="simplefilter li">`, me arroje un alert dinamico.

Entonces de que manera puedo hacer de que el `javascript` manipule elementos que se cargan dinamicamente en `html` pero que se encuentran dentro de un js?

Agradecería el interés.

Comment: te he dejado ejemplo de como hacerlo. Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 1):

ya que estas usando jQuery:

Puedes agregarle una clase a tu `<li>`

```
$(".simplefilter").append('<li class="dinamicamente">' + desc +'</li>');
```

luego utilizar un manejador para el evento click en tu clase:

```
$(".dinamicamente").click(function(){

           //tu funcion dinamica por ejemplo
           alert($(this).html());
        });
```

ejemplo completo

```js
    
    function addli(desc){
    $(".simplefilter").append('<li class="dinamicamente">' + desc +'</li>');

    $(".dinamicamente").click(function(){
    
       //tu funcion dinamica por ejemplo
       alert($(this).html());
    });
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="addli('perro')">a</button>
<button onClick="addli('vaca')">b</button>
<ul class='simplefilter'></ul>
```

tienes que crear el manejador después de crear tus elementos

Comment: Hola @Jorge gracias por el interes, intente realizar lo que me has propuesto pero no me ha funcionado. :(

Comment: @JDavid agregue un ejemplo para que veas la implementacion

Answer (score 1):

debes usar `find(...).each(...)` para accionar en cada elemento dentro de `<ul>`.

Ejemplo:

```js
//Simple filter controls
$('.simplefilter').click(function() {
 $(this).find('li').each(function() {
  if(this == event.target) {
   $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
   $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
 });
});
$(".simplefilter").append('<li>filter 1</li>');
$(".simplefilter").append('<li>filter 2</li>');
$(".simplefilter").append('<li>filter 3</li>');
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="simplefilter">
  Simple filter controls:
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola @fwBasic gracias por el interes, el ejemplo es valido pero resulta que como los li estan corriendo dentro de un JS no me funciona de esa manera

Comment: igualmente te funciona, modificare el ejemplo creando los li dinamicamente.

Comment: revisa nuevamente el ejemplo ahora los `<li>` se crean dinamicamente, y recuerda calificar la respuesta que mas se adecue a tus requerimientos, Saludos!! ;))...